# xsd to java bean jaxb field name

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have created java beans from the following xsd files

person.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           jxb:version="2.0">

    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jxb:globalBindings>
                <jxb:serializable uid="1"/>
            </jxb:globalBindings>
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package name="com.thiyanesh"/>
            </jxb:schemaBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>

    <xs:element name="person">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

team.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           jxb:version="2.0">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="person.xsd"/>

    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jxb:globalBindings>
                <jxb:serializable uid="2"/>
            </jxb:globalBindings>
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package name="com.thiyanesh"/>
            </jxb:schemaBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>

    <xs:element name="team">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="person" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The objective is to define Person as separate class and include list of person in Team class.

Now the class Team contains the field

```
List<Person> person;
```

Is there a way to give a different name to this field? Say "members".

```
List<Person> members;
```

I may not be able to edit the generated class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bindings works fine

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:namespace="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/namespace-prefix">

    <bindings schemaLocation="../path/team.xsd">

            <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='team']//xs:complexType//xs:sequence//xs:element[@ref='person']">
                <property name="members"/>
            </bindings>

    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

else

```
    <xs:element name="team">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="person" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <jxb:property name="members" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit the generated class and rename the field (but keep or add @XmlElement(name="person") on top.

You can also customize the schema binding for example:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html

but it is a pain, comparing to simple annotation. It is easier to just accept person instead of member.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without touching the generate class? Updated the question too.

Comment: is added the link to schema customization